# How to add custom field in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to give an option in my  application to let the use choose maximum 3 custom fields of his choice, how is it possible ? I know their is some easy solution for this but can't get that.

I mean is it possible in rails to let the user select the label for extra fields he wants in his data. FOr example i have a table **fruit** with fields **name, type, taste** and two extra fields **extra_field1 and extra_field2**. The first 3 fields are visible on the form with same label and a link to add custom fields, after clicking on that link user gets a form where he can label the extra fields of his choice like person **A** name them **rate and weight** while person **B** name them **rate and color** etc. After the name setting the extra field should be visible to user on the form every time he creates a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be that you can have model `CustomField`, set available custom fields in `custom_fields` table. Use multi select dropdown to allow user to select custom fields, as many as he want.
And there will be an intermediate model which will have `user_id`, 'custom_fields_id' and `value`.

Your associations might be like this.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :custom_fields, :through => 'UserCustomFields'
```

**user_custom_field.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :custom_field
```

**custom_field.rb**

```
has_many :users, :through => 'UserCustomFields'
```

Comment: You can add a field `field_label` in `custom_fields` table.

Comment: i am thinking about adding the custom field in the same table with 3 label fields to avoide complexity

Comment: You should has extra table for custom fields to avoid horizontal growth of table in future.

Comment: this is only for current requirement, i don't think this will be expand more in future as i allowed only three fields to be added in extra

Comment: Then simply add 6 fields in your table, 3 for labels and 3 for values.

Comment: Oops i am so confused can you please explain your first answer, this will be very helpful for me

Comment: You have two options, 1-you can have custom fields model `CustomField` with fields `id, name` and an intermediate model `UserCustomFields` with fields `id, user_id, custom_field_id, value` and implement associations i mentioned in my answer. You can set custom fields manually and make them available to select on for users.

Comment: 2-You can have a model `CustomField` with fields `id, name, value, user_id`. now your relations will become `User has_many :custom_fields` and 'CustomField belongs_to :user'. You will fill up name and value in you views for custom_field and save it against user.

Comment: sir i have used you solution and it works for me, i have post my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

I have added a new table to database with name "custome_field" that contains the followitn columns:

```
mysql> desc custom_fields;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| voucher_type  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| custom_label1 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| custom_label2 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| custom_label3 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And added three new column to my table a as custom_field1, custom_field2 and custom_field3. 
Now i can set label in custom_field table and class for which i want the custom fields and use them in form i need.

Thanks to @Ramiz Raja for supporting me on this.